# RefererNotAllowedMapError despite having referer specified in Key Restrictions

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, api-key, http-referer

I'm implementing the Maps JavaScript API onto a site, like I've done a thousand times, but this time, when I restrict the key to specific HTTP referers for the site and dev sites it'll appear on, it doesn't work.

I've tried just about every permutation of the URLs, including with/without the protocol. I'm getting the `RefererNotAllowedMapError` error with a note "Your site URL to be authorized:" showing *the exact URL* that I've already added to the referers list.

Variants I've tried thus far:

- mydevsite.com/
- mydevsite.com/*
- *.mydevsite.com/
- *.mydevsite.com/*
- http://mydevsite.com/
- http://mydevsite.com/*

None of my other sites have had this issue, but it's been several months since I needed to implement Maps on a site.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but when I tried creating the key on a different project, or adding the referers to a key meant for a different site, it worked. It seems new keys on that particular project are broken when restricted.